# Adjusting t-stat for rolling mean feature in time series regression?

Tags: regression, standard-error

Say we have a timeseries data $x_t$ and we are trying to predict $y_t$ with the following:

$$y_t = \alpha + \beta f_t$$
where $f_r = \frac{1}{3}(x_t +x_{t-1} + x_{t-2})$.
Now, your t-stat is $3$. How would you adjust the t-stat without running a new regression in order to account for the autocorrelation?

I would typically use the correct standard errors to compute this... but is there some sort of back of the envelope adjustment to make to regular standard errors when you have this type of correlation or overlapping features?

$H_0: \beta = 0$

Comment: For clarity, do you mean the $t$ statistic for $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }\beta = 0$?

Comment: What is the purpose of the "t-stat" and how do you estimate or know the autocorrelation?

Comment: t-test for $H_0: \beta = 0$. There is autocorrelation because of the overlapping $x$ values I suppose. Apologies I did not have enough points to reply before.

Comment: Consider expressing your model as the multiple regression $$y_t = \alpha + \beta_0x_t + \beta_1x_{t-1} + \beta_2x_{t-2} + \varepsilon.$$  Fit it with ordinary least squares and test the hypothesis $H_0:\beta_0/3=\beta_1/3=\beta_2/3=0$ with a standard $F$ test.

Comment: Yes, but what factor would you adjust your t-stat by?